# How hide/visible element in accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to when accordion element is visible span and img element display and when it invisible their not displayed. in fact user click on one of element to display it img and span add it and when user slide toggle span and img hide.

[image]

```js
$("#accordion > li > div").click(function(){
 
    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
        $('#accordion ul').slideUp(300);
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});
 
$('#accordion ul:eq(0)').show();
```

```css
#accordion {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    width: 170px;
}
#accordion div {
    display: block;
    background-color: #FF9927;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5 5 5 7px;
}
#accordion ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
#accordion ul{
    display: none;
}
#accordion ul li {
    font-weight: normal;
    cursor: auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 7px;
}
#accordion a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="accordion">
    <li>
      <div>Sports <img src='' width='25' height='25'> <br><span>#20</span></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Golf</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><div>Technology<img src='' width='25' height='25'> <br><span>#20</span></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please add little more description to your question, its not clarifying what you want to achieve?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i could interpret was you are looking for something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/L034j1gh/

```
#accordion {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    width: 170px;
}
#accordion div {
    display: block;
    background-color: #FF9927;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5 5 5 7px;
}
#accordion ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
#accordion ul{
    display: none;
}
#accordion ul li {
    font-weight: normal;
    cursor: auto;
    padding: 0 0 0 7px;
}
#accordion a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#accordion > li > div>img{
 display:none;   

}

$("#accordion > li > div").click(function(){

    if(false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
          $(this).children('img').show();
        $('#accordion ul').slideUp(300);
    }
    else
    {
         $(this).children('img').hide();
    }
    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);

});

$('#accordion ul:eq(0)').show();
$('#accordion > li:first-child > div>img').show();

<ul id="accordion">
    <li>
      <div>Sports <img src='' width='25' height='25'> <br><span>#20</span></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Golf</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><div>Technology<img src='' width='25' height='25'> <br><span>#20</span></div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">iPhone</a></li>

        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: its has a tiny small bug. when click  second item not hide span and img first item.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vanntile/07tjugb5/)

If I got it right, this is what you need(click on link to toggle visibility on image and span)

The code of the fiddle is:

```
<ul id="accordion">
<li>
    <div id="firstdiv">Sports
        <img alt="b" src='' width='25' height='25' />
        <br/><span>#20</span>

    </div>
    <ul id="firstul">
        <li><a href="#">Golf</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <div id="seconddiv">Technology
        <img alt="a" src='' width='25' height='25'>
        <br/><span>#20</span>

    </div>
    <ul id="secondul">
        <li><a href="#">iPhone</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

```
$("#accordion > li > div").hide();
$("#accordion > li > #firstul").click(function () {
    $("#accordion > li > #firstdiv").slideToggle(300);
});
$("#accordion > li > #secondul").click(function () {
    $("#accordion > li > #seconddiv").slideToggle(300);
});
```

Hope it helps you.